# Data migration for a huge amount of pages

Tags: c#, episerver

I have a base page with the **Field1** and **SomeBlock**

```
public abstract class BasePage : PageData
{
    [CultureSpecific]
    [Display(Name = "Field1")]
    public virtual string Field1 { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "SomeBlock")]
    public virtual SomeBlock SomeBlock { get; set; }
}
public class SomeBlock : BlockData
{
    [CultureSpecific]
    [Display(Name = "Field1")]
    public virtual string Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have to move the **Field1** into **SomeBlock** inside the **BasePage** and move all existing data from `BasePage.Field1` to `BasePage.SomeBlock.Field1`

For this purposes I have created a job that looks like:

```
    private void MigrateFields()
    {
        var repo = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();

        var descendents  = repo.GetDescendents(_root).Where(p => SafeGetContent(repo, p) is BasePage).Select(repo.Get<BasePage>);

        foreach (var basePage in descendents)
        {

            BasePage writeablePage = (BasePage)basePage .CreateWritableClone();

            if (basePage.SomeBlock == null)
                basePage.SomeBlock = new SomeBlock ();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(basePage.SomeBlock.Field1))
            {
                basePage.SomeBlock.Field1 = basePage.Field1;
            }


            DataFactory.Instance.Save(writeablePage, SaveAction.Publish, AccessLevel.NoAccess);
        }
    }
```

Everything works just fine if I have about 1000 of pages. However if the site has >20000 it looks like the job just dies.

Comment: You could also look into *migration steps*, they're commonly used when properties are changed/renamed.

Comment: Thanks @TedNyberg, I'll try

Comment: @TedNyberg As I can see from the documentation - I could only rename the Property or Content Type. But here I should move Property to the Block

Comment: I could be misunderstanding the use case, but couldn't you create a migration step where "Field1" is considered the old property and "SomeBlock" is considered the new one? I.e., like you renamed and re-typed the "Field1" property?

Comment: I am trying to move Field1 from Page to the Block that would be inside of the same Page. I don't see if MigrationStep could help here. I could extend the sample with the Block so it would be easier to read

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought it was within the same content type. How is `MigrateFields()` invoked? Also, I'd include logging to get a feel for what is actually happening.

Comment: It is called from the scheduled job. We don't have loggers there :( As I can see locally - the job runs for a certain period of time - and then EpiServer admin is not responding. After the restart - job status would be "running". And it would never change. For 1000 pages it could take more then 10 minutes to run

Comment: Which Episerver version is it? Long-running scheduled jobs shouldn't be a problem. However, you might want the scheduled job to periodically report status to the UI so that you don't have to wonder whether or not it is running. :) I would strongly recommend adding logging though, nothing ever just "dies" without giving off some sort of trace. :)

Comment: @TedNyberg after investigation - it looks like it has an overflow when I am trying to get all descendants...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with

```
var descendents  = repo.GetDescendents(_root)
.Where(p => SafeGetContent(repo, p) is BasePage).Select(repo.Get<BasePage>);
```

It doesn't work with a huge amount of pages. This kind of code fits much better for this issue:

```
var references = DataFactory.Instance.GetDescendents(RootPageReference);
var pages = DataFactory.Instance.GetItems(references,
LanguageSelector.AutoDetect()).Where(x => !x.IsDeleted).OfType<BasePage>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are doing a Get to the database twice for every page with GetSafeContent and then Get after that. You could start by doing a single Get and then check for the correct type after that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I don't feel that it would help in this case. Need more improvements...